# Laravel: How to send parameters to JasperReports's report via URL

Tags: php, laravel-5, jasper-reports

I created a report using *iReport* that selects data from a table in my database.

There are 2 fields `fromdate` and `todate`.

I tried a parameter of the id and the name of the customer all works fine.

The problem is: when I want to send the 2 parameters in the URL `fromdate` and `todate` I am trying to send the date like: `2014-02-02` and `2017-02-02`.

The URL: `localhost/reports/getreportservice/2014-02-02&2017-02-02`

Then in my PHP file am converting those dates from string to date using `strtotime` function and changing the format. Then am sending the 2 parameters to the report.

In the reports I put the 2 parameters type: `java.util.Date` and in MySQL the types of the fields are: DATETIME.

The report giving me the error: `cannot process the report`. It's the same error whenever we get something wrong in the error. No more logs.

Anyone has a solution to let the JasperReports's report accepts those 2 parameters?

I tried to preview my report in *iReport* it works fine and got my data. I tried the id param and name all works fine. The problem is in accepting the dates from the URL.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use JasperPHP\JasperPHP;
class ReportController extends Controller {
public function getReportTest($fromdate,$todate){
    $fromdatee=  strtotime($fromdate);
    $fromdateee=Date('d/M/y',$fromdatee);
    $todatee=  strtotime($todate);
    $todateee=date('d/M/y',$todatee);

    $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
    $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
    $ext = "html";
    $data_file = public_path() . '/report/CancelAck.xml';
    $driver = 'xml';
    $xml_xpath = '/CancelResponse/CancelResult/ID';

    \JasperPHP::process(
        public_path() . '/report/newreporttest.jrxml',
        $output,
        array($ext),
        array('fromdate' =>$fromdateee, 'todate' =>$todateee),
        array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' =>'',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'database' => 'test',
  'port' => '3306',
 ),
        array('data_file' => $data_file, 'driver' => $driver, 'xml_xpath' =>      $xml_xpath),
        false,
        false
    )->execute();

 //        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
//        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
//        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;    filename='.time().'_CancelAck.'.$ext);
 //        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output.'.'.$ext));
    flush();
    readfile($output.'.'.$ext);
    unlink($output.'.'.$ext);

}
```

}

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: have your tried ?fromDate=....&endDate=......

Comment: sure .. same problem